# Cannot find symbol. Is looking in Superclass instead of subclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I have a program that interprets and sorts data for a car dealer, and there is an error when trying to retrieve the color of the cars stored in an array.

Here is the main class and its sub class.

```
class Car
{
protected String model;
protected int price;
protected int year;

public Car(String m, int y,  int p)
{
    model = m;
    price = p;
    year = y;
}
}


class NewCar extends Car
{
protected String color;

public NewCar(String m, int y, int p, String c)
{
    super(m, y, p);
    color = c;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Model: " + model + "\n"
    + "Year: " + year + "\n"
    + "Price: $" + price + "\n"
    + "Color: " + color + "\n"
    + "Selling Price: " + price + "\n\n";
}
}
```

Here is another class in which the error occurs, at `if(cars[z].color.equals(shade))`.
The program cannot find variable color in class Car.

```
  class CarDealerShip
    {

        public String printAllCarsOfColor(String shade)
    {
        String s = "";

        for(int z = 0; z < i; z++)
        {
            if(cars[z].color.equals(shade))
            {
                s += "Car " + (z + 1) + "\n" + cars[z].toString();
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
```

How can I have the program look in class NewCar where variable color exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a requirement that `color` has to be in class `NewCar` you could use the `instanceof` operator and then cast it:

```
class CarDealerShip
{
    public String printAllCarsOfColor(String shade)
    {
        String s = "";

        for(int z = 0; z < i; z++)
        {
            if (cars[z] instanceof NewCar)
            {
                NewCar nc = (NewCar)cars[z];
                if (nc.color.equals(shade))
                {
                    s += "Car " + (z + 1) + "\n" + nc.toString();
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

You actually skip every `Car` that it not a `NewCar` and use only those that are an instance of the class `NewCar`.

Answer (score 3):

Your array `cars` appears to be of type `Car[]`.  With a reference variable of `Car` after you have referenced the array element, there is no way to tell if it refers to a `Car`, a `NewCar`, or another subclass of `Car`.

It looks like you expect `cars[z]` to have the attribute `color`, so perhaps `cars` should be of type `NewCar[]` instead of `Car[]`.

Another option is to move the attribute `color` to the superclass `Car` so any `Car` can have a color.

Comment: Doing "Car cars[] = new NewCar[80];" does not get rid of the error, also the 'color' attribute HAS to be in subclass 'NewCar'

Comment: @BribeGuntails - He said ... `"NewCar cars[] = new NewCar[80];"`

Answer (score 1):

When using protected access the field will be available in classes that are within the same package or are a subclass of the base class.  I'm assuming the class `CarDealerShip` which  accesses the `color` field is not within the same package or does not extend `Car`.

Answer (score 1):

The `color` is protected in `NewCar`. You can access protected variable only in sub classes. You need to move `color` to `Car` and add a `public String getColor()` method in your `Car` to make it available for the classes which are not part of the `Car` inheritance hierarchy.

```
public String getColor() {
   return color;
}
```

and then your condition would be

```
if(cars[z].getColor().equals(shade))
```

**Update**

In case you want `color` to be in `NewCar`, you should add the `public String getColor();` method in `NewCar` and your `cars[]` should be `NewCar[]`, something like,

```
NewCar cars[] = new NewCar[arraySize]();
```

with this you will loose the inheritance capabilities, you can not use `Car cars[] = new NewCar[arraySize]` anymore.

Comment: Variable color HAS to be in class NewCar, it's a requirement.

Comment: Changing the array wholly to NewCar breaks the subclass UsedCar of class Car

Comment: Yes, it will break the `polymorphism`. Unless you move the `color` to super class, you can not use with `Car[]`. Your `cars[]` holds only `NewCar`s or any other objects like `UsedCar` ?